# Reactjs findDOMNode on components

Tags: post, components, reactjs

I have a component which uses another component

```
render: function(){
    return(
        <div className={"col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"}>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className="panel panel-default">
                    <div className="panel-body">
                        <CustomerForm />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" className={"btn btn-default"} onClick={this.handleFormSubmit} value="Post">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

There is not problem when I try to display the data but,
**the problem comes when I want to POST the data to my backend using this function**

```
handleSubmit: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var firstName = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.firstName).value.trim();

        if (!firstName) {
            return;
        }

        this.props.onCustomerSubmit({firstName: firstName});
        React.findDOMNode(this.refs.firstName).value = '';

        return;
}
```

Because findDOMNode only works on mounted components and  is a child component I get the error *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null*

Is there a good way to solve such a issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about looking deeper into your `refs`?

In your `render()` function:

```
<CustomerForm ref={'customerForm'} />
```

and in your `handleSubmit()` function:

```
React.findDOMNode(this.refs.customerForm.refs.firstName).value = '';
```

but this adds some pretty tight coupling between this class and your `CustomForm` class.  Perhaps a better approach is to refactor?

Comment: Thank you ! This was the answer I was looking for.  I would strongly take your advise on refactoring, would you have a suggestions/ advise on how to do it ? The problem is that there will be several sections to the forms such as <CustomerForm /> , <BookForm />. I thought a good idea would be to split these into components and mount them in the <Form /> component

Comment: Well first, instead of grabbing a DOM node and setting its value you should pass the value in as a property if the value is "owned" by the parent component.  If actions handled inside the child can change its value, then it should own that value as `state` with the parent optionally providing an `initialValue`

Comment: If your components are representing forms, it is probably better for them to render the entire `form` element... having this parent form is a bad idea imo.